# Notepad++: Strange character with non english language

Tags: notepad++, windows-10

In win 7 I don't have any problem with notepad++ when using Persian language but after upgrading to windows 10, I can't type characters correctly (see bellow picture).

Already entered characters are shown correctly, also if I type in another program like windows notepad and copy paste it to notepad++ there is no problem.

The document is already in `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.
I don't have any problem in another language.
 
Control panel>Region>administrative>System local is already set to my language

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem dissolved with renaming main application from `npp.exe` to `Notepad++.exe`. I don't know the reason.